# Moving a picture box in timer C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, 2d, picturebox

Ok so please keep answers very direct and i must say i am very new to C#, i don't know a lot of stuff. Without further adieu my problem.
I am trying to move a picture box horizontally across the screen on a timer.The timer must go infinitely. I have tried all i currently know in C# and searched around quite a lot but nothing answered my exact question which is what i need because of my lesser knowledge of C#. For the last two weeks i worked on graphics mostly and the rest of that was trying to get this to work, So i have no code in my game. This is because for anything to work i need this part to be working. My game is 2D topdown. Any and all help is appreciated.

Thank you for taking the time to read.

*Edit*

No more answers needed, Thank you Odrai for the answer, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pictureBox.Location = new Point(x, y) or set pictureBox.Left/Top/Right. You can define x and y as variabels and initialize them with a default value. Increment x on timer tick.

Sample 1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Random _random 

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _random = new Random();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = _random.Next(0, 500);
        int y = _random.Next(0, 500);
        pictureBox1.Top += y;
        pictureBox1.Left += x;
    }
}
```

Sample 2:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.SuspendLayout();
  pictureBox.Location = new Point(picust.Location.X + 10, picust.Location.Y);
  this.ResumeLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add two buttons with title LEFT and RIGHT to a form and write the following code.
It might give you an idea, how to do simple moving animations.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int difference = 0;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer.Interval = 15;
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Left += difference;
    }

    private void btnLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        difference = -2;
    }

    private void btnRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        difference = 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code it will work :

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int width = this.Width; // get the width of Form.

    if(pictureBox1.Location.X > width - pictureBox1.Width) //to check condition if pic box is touch the boundroy of form width
    {
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(1, pictureBox1.Location.Y); // pic box is set to the new point. here 1 is indicate of X coordinate.
    }
    else
    {
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X + 100, pictureBox1.Location.Y); // to move picture box from x coordinate by 100 Point.
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

//Try This //

picturebox1.Location = 0,0;